# Apply word wrap style to Ext JS Chart axis labels

Tags: extjs, charts, label, axis, styling

I'm working on an ExtJS chart. The axis labels of the chart is having lengthy texts. At the edges of the Chart the texts are cut off. How to word wrap style to Ext JS Chart axis labels?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply word wrap style to extjs Chart label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480873/apply-word-wrap-style-to-extjs-chart-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.x-form-label#myLabel {
        width: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

adding newlines every n words with a renderer could also work

Heres the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16t3)

```
    renderer: function(v) {
        //adds newline every 5th word
        return v.replace(/((?:\w+ ){5})/gi, "$1\n");
    }
```