# Apply word wrap style to extjs Chart label

Tags: extjs, charts

I'm working on extjs chart. when the axis labels have big texts, at the edges of the Chart the texts are cut off. How to word wrap long labels? Any suggestions? 
Here is my code:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15ef

Answer (score 3):

adding newlines every n words should do the trick. Try adding a renderer to your axes label. Implemented in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16t3) and it isn't cutting off anymore

```
    renderer: function(v) {
        return v.replace(/((?:\w+ ){5})/gi, "$1\n"); //newline every 5th word
    }
```

[image: fiddle screenshot]

If you have extremely long labels that still cut off even with word wrap, you could truncate the labels after n characters. Ext has a cool [ellipsis](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-ellipsis) function for that

```
renderer: function(v) {
    v = Ext.util.Format.ellipsis(v,80); //truncate after 80 characters
    return v.replace(/((?:\w+ ){5})/gi, "$1\n");
}
```

Comment: if the texts is much bigger than it is now it will still cut of right ?

Comment: I tried it with 16 words and it didn't cut it off. How long are your labels? Can you just trim them if they are longer than 16 words? So have the first 16 words and end with "..."

Answer (score 1):

You may insert `\n` at any place you want to break the line.

Comment: I did like that but it still cuts off text, how can I prevent that?

Comment: How about adding some blanks at the end of the text?