# Extjs chart axis text overflow

Tags: extjs5, linechart

I am using Extjs cartesian chart, the problem is when the axis labels have big texts, at the edges of the Chart the texts are cut off. Here is my code example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15ef
here is the image:
[image]

Comment: is it an option to truncate the text if it is too long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply word wrap style to extjs Chart label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480873/apply-word-wrap-style-to-extjs-chart-label)